# mySQLが起動しなくなりました。解決策をご教示お願いします！

Tags: mysql, xampp

プログラミング初心者です。試行錯誤して試しましたが解決できず質問させていただきます。

xamppにインストールしているmysqlが起動しなくなり、データベースが使えず現在運用しているブログも停止している状況です。
問題が起きる直前に行っていたことは、
①localのインストール （サイト作成中にhostsファイルの書き換え失敗）
②新しくwordpressインストールのため、データベースを作ろうとしたがユーザーの作成が出来なかった。

mysql起動失敗の画面キャプチャを取りました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

また、mysqllogの内容は以下になります。

```
2020-03-15  6:55:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: The first innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' did not exist. A new tablespace will be created!
2020-03-15  6:55:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-03-15  6:55:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-03-15  6:55:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-03-15  6:55:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-03-15  6:55:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-03-15  6:55:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-03-15  6:55:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-03-15  6:55:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1' size to 10 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-03-15  6:55:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1' size is now 10 MB.
2020-03-15  6:55:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 size to 5242880 bytes
2020-03-15  6:55:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile1 size to 5242880 bytes
2020-03-15  6:55:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 to C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile0
2020-03-15  6:55:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45786
2020-03-15  6:55:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
2020-03-15  6:55:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
2020-03-15  6:55:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-03-15  6:55:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2020-03-15  6:55:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating tablespace and datafile system tables.
2020-03-15  6:55:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating sys_virtual system tables.
2020-03-15  6:55:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-03-15  6:55:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-03-15  6:55:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-03-15  6:55:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-03-15  6:55:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.16 started; log sequence number 0; transaction id 7
2020-03-15  6:55:54 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-03-15  6:55:54 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: エラーログの情報も有用です。ubuntuの私の環境では /var/log/mysql/error.logです。※その他のOSのログ格納場所は知りません。

Comment: akira ejiriさま
ありがとうございます。ubuntuの環境も参考にさせていただきます。
私の環境はwindowsですが、他にエラーログが無いか確認してみます。

Answer (score 2):

Windows Event Viewerを見ろとも書かれています。のでまずそれを。。。

とりあえず、怪しい点を

> 新しくwordpressインストールのため、データベースを作ろうとしたがユーザーの作成が出来なかった。

これはどのような手段で？新しくMySQLをインストールしたとかしてます？
画面キャプチャの情報と記載のログ（NOTEだけになっているので、ほかにWARNかERRORが出力されているログがあるはずですが。。。）だけではなんともなのでほかにログでてませんか？
⇒元ログにPortがどうとか書かれているので気になります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございますm(__)m

ユーザーの作成はxamppから入れるphpMyAdminから追加しようとしました。

ログが保存されているフォルダを見ましたが、他にログは見当たりませんでした。もう一度エラーログも確認しましたが、WARN,ERRORは見つからなかったです。

ご指摘ありましたイベントビューアーを確認してみたら、２件エラーが発生していました。

Comment: 2.create database です。

イベントビューアーのエラーは以下の２件でした。原因など分かりますでしょうか
１ Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table '.\mysql\user' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
２ mysqld.exe: Table '.\mysql\user' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed

Comment: userテーブル飛んでいて使いもにならないっていってますよね。自動修復試みて失敗という。。。無駄かもしれませんが、以下のサイトにコマンドでの復旧方法ありますが、参考になるかどうか。。。pentan.info/sql/mysql/table_crashed_repaired.html 

jitsu102.hatenablog.com/entry/20120106/1325799325　こちらも参考になりますが、innoDBではr使えないとか。

あと、前のコメントを消してしまいました。ごめんなさい。

Comment: コマンド叩いてみましたが、mysqlにアクセスできないとのことなので、最後の手段ですが再インストールしてみます。。。
今までただインストールしただけで使っていたので焦りましたが、勉強になりました。貴重なお時間を頂きありがとうございました。

Comment: お力になれず申し訳ないです。幸いデータが存在しないようなので、安心しました。運用時にはバックアップをお忘れなく。